# How do I automate tasks I do in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, automation

Please excuse me for the lame question.

My concern - I have to create a report downloading the data available in certain tools but before clicking on the download button, i have to choose few queue names(60 queues) out of 250 queues which are not in order. Its too irritating that I should keep scrolling and searching for the queues in the small drop down box checking the queue names which I want and the download. (time consuming as well)

**I macros** didn't work for me.

(These tools are intranet based tools)

This is my daily activity. Is there any way that i can make it automated through VBA or something ?

**Thanks in advance !**

Comment: For web automation, you can use Selenium or Katalon Studio or any of the other Selenium based tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only simple macros you can use applications like "Simple Macro Recorder". It is free and simple. Selenium is best solution for you if you need get some conditions. Selenium give you full control.